# Preciso pegar uma coluna com varias informações redundantes e pegar apenas uma delas

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba, excel-vba

Possuo uma `combo-box` onde necessito que ele percorra a `coluna "A"` e pegue apenas uma informação de cada (pois possue redundância dela), um exemplo seria departamente no caso há redundancia e não usa-se uma chave primária

O código que alimenta a combo-box:

```
Public Function carregaCombobox()
    cmbDepartment.Clear
    Worksheets("Full Control").range("A3").Select
    Dim itemLista As String
    Do While ActiveCell.Value <> ""
        If verificaItem(ActiveCell.Value) = False Then
            itemLista = ActiveCell.Value
            If cmbDepartment.ListCount >= 2 Then
                 cmbDepartment.AddItem itemLista
            Else
                cmbDepartment.AddItem itemLista
            End If

        End If
         ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select
    Loop


End Function
```

> Porém quando executo ele retorna um erro: '381': Could not get the
>   List Property. Invalid property array index.

Ele possui uma `função` para verificar se existe ou não a informação que ele pega da célula selecionada pelo `Do While` que é esse:

```
Public Function verificaItem(itemPlanilha As String) As Boolean
    Dim i As Long
    Dim itemLista As String
    verificaItem = False
    If cmbDepartment.ListCount > 0 Then
        For i = 0 To cmbDepartment.ListCount
            itemLista = cmbDepartment.List(i, 0)
            If itemLista = itemPlanilha Then
                verificaItem = True
                Exit Function
            End If
        Next i
    End If  
End Function
```

> Exemplificando:
>
> Tenho essas informações em uma coluna

```
  A
Parede
Parede
Teto
Teto
Parede
Chão
```

> E quero apenas as informações sem repeti-las em uma combo-box
>   aparecendo então assim

```
Parede
Teto
Chão
```

Comment: Não sei se entendi direito. Você deseja inserir valores não duplicados na ComboBox?

Comment: Não, eu tenho valores duplicados na tabela, porém eu só quero um deles, por exemplo tenho assim (valor1, valor1, valor1, valor2, valor2, valor1)-> gostaria de pegar apenas assim (valor1,valor2) entendeu?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Se o ComboBox estiver num formulário, o código deve ser inserido na Subrotina `Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()` para carregar os dados da ComboBox ao inicializar o formulário.

#### Código

```
Dim x As Long, ncell as Long
Dim Rng As Range, c As Range
Dim ws As Worksheet

Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("nome_planilha")

With ws

    ncell = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
    Me.ComboBox1.Clear

    For y = 1 To ncell
        Set c = .Cells(y, 1)
        Set Rng = .Range(.Cells(2, 1), .Cells(y, 1))
        x = Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIf(Rng, c)
        If x = 1 Then Me.ComboBox1.AddItem c
    Next y
End With
```

#### Variáveis

Este código realiza um loop e verifica a quantidade de valores em que a string da célula atual aparece, com a função `CountIf`. Adiciona ao ComboBox somente na primeira vez em que a string aparece na coluna.

- `ws`: é a variável com a planilha em que os dados se encontram
- `ncell`: é a última linha preenchida da coluna "A"
- `c`: é a célula atual em que o loop é realizado
- `x`: é a quantidade de elementos daquela string presentes no intervalo
- `Rng`: é o intervalo, que é incrementado a cada loop

> Obs.: Este código realiza um loop em cada linha por ser mais fácil. Se a quantidade de dados for muito grande, é necessário preencher um array com os dados da coluna e obter os dados únicos no vetor, um exemplo de função que pode ser utilizada:

```
Public Function unicoArr(ByRef Arr As Variant, x As Long) As Object
    Set unicoArr = New Collection
    Dim a
    Dim i As Long

    On Error Resume Next
    For i = LBound(Arr) To UBound(Arr)
        a = Arr(i)(x)
        unicoArr.Add a, a
    Next

End Function
```

Comment: Muito obrigado, consegui com esse código, me ajudou muito